# JMeter - View currrent request before getting response

Tags: jmeter

When running JMeter in GUI mode, sometimes request stuck or takes a long (minute or more) time to get a response

Is there a way to view request before response received?

Obviously Listeners are executed after Sampler finish because of Scoping rules, but is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The simplest and the most obvious option is sending the request somewhere else, i.e. [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost), [example.com](http://example.com/), wherever. You will get response immediately therefore will be able to inspect the request details using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener
2. A little bit more complicated option is printing the request details to *jmeter.log* file using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter) which will query `sampler` instance which is a shorthand for [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html) class like:

   ```
   log.info('URL: ' + (sampler.getUrl() as String) + sampler.getQueryString())
   log.info('Parameters: ')
   sampler.getArguments().each {arg -> 
       log.info(arg.getObjectValue() as String)
   } 
   if (sampler.getCookieManager() != null) {
       log.info('Cookies: ') 
       sampler.getCookieManager().getCookies().each { cookie ->
           log.info(cookie.getObjectValue() as String)
        }
   }

   if (sampler.getHeaderManager() != null) {
       log.info('Headers:')
       sampler.getHeaderManager().getHeaders().each {header -> 
           log.info(header.getObjectValue() as String)
       }
   }
   //etc
   ```

   Demo:

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Following Master Apache JMeter book, filling the Timeouts can prevent such issues:

> Fill the Timeouts (milliseconds) option of HTTP Request allows you not to wait for
>   a SUT response indefinitely.
>
> This will provide the following benefits :
>
> • Allow JMeter to stop at the end of the test without waiting indefinitely for
>   hanged requests. By default the timeout is infinite in HTTP Request